# Multiple RelativeSlugHandler

Tags: doctrine-extensions

I want to do something like that:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
 *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="product"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="slug"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-")
 *      }),
 *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="flavour"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="slug"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-")
 *      })
 * }, separator="-", updatable=true, fields={"size"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $slug;
```

This code runs well, but only the last slug handler configured works. How can I make this work?

Comment: Same problem here, please let me know if you managed to solve it.

Comment: @3ND I couldn't, a RelativeSlugHandler can be used just for one field.

Comment: Thats what i thought, thank you

Comment: I opened a PR that would allow you to make things work: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/pull/1734